# What is the specification of the Postman's pm.test() function?

Tags: postman

In Postman you can write tests to be executed after requests.

This is the [documentation](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test-scripts/) and these are the [examples](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test-examples/). But I don't see/find the specification of the `pm.test()` function.

- What does it return?
- Does it get any arguments?

Comment: This is probably the doc you're looking for - https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#pmtest

Comment: Thank @DannyDainton! This looks like what I was looking for. If you want you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The information regarding the `pm.test` function and the arguments that it takes can be found here:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#pmtest